# Data factory foreach with global parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data factory, I want to iterate over some of my Global Parameters in a foreach loop:

[image]

Unfortunately, the @array declartion is wrong as shown above and giving this error:

[image]

Any idea?

The global parameters are correctly defined and published:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use create array function as below.

```
@createArray(pipeline().globalParameters.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,pipeline().globalParameters.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb)
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

For more information about adf functions check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) doc.